# Triggering keyframe on mouseEvent

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, events, css-animations

I am trying to trigger a CSS animation on mouseover event. Sadly, it does not work as desired.

This is what I tried. I am trying to achieve the same motion on mouseover as the keyframe declaration within CSS would.

It works as desired in Firefox +Chrome(mobile) but not in Chrome (PC).

```js
const element = document.querySelector('.circ');
element.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
console.log(1);
    element.style.animation = "move 1000ms infinite ease-in-out alternate";
});
element.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
//mouseout triggers automatically following mouseover without provocation
console.log(2); 
    element.style.animation = "none";
});
```

```css
.circ {
     pointer-events: all;
}
 .rect {
     pointer-events: none;
}
 @keyframes move {
     0% {
         transform: translateX(0);
    }
     100% {
         transform: translateX(500px);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container" class="svg-container">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 600 100">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="530" height="200" fill="#EFEFEF"></rect>
      <g class="crcl">  
        <circle class="circ" cx="10" cy="50" r="10" fill="blue"></circle>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to achieve the desired effect with existing `mouseover` and `mouseout` by overlaying the exact same transparent element as the recipient `keyframe` element. Then add a listener on the overlaid element to program the movement on the bottom element.

Such as

```js
const data = [
    [0, 0], //bottom for action i=0, top for overlaying i=1
    [1, 1],
    [2, 2]
];

const svg = d3.select('svg');

const grp =
    svg
    .append('g')
    .classed('all', true);

const circ = grp
    .selectAll('g')
    .data(data)
    .join('g')
    .attr('id', (_, i) => i)
    .attr('transform', (_, i) => `translate(0 ${20*(i+1)})`)
    .selectAll('circle')
    .data(function(_, i) {
        return data[i]
    })
    .join('circle')
    .attr('id', function(_, i) {
        return d3.select(this).node().parentNode.id + i
    })
    .attr('cx', (_, i) => 20)
    .attr('cy', (_, i) => 20)
    .attr('r', '5')
    .attr('fill', (_, i) => { if (i === 0) { return 'blue' } else { return 'transparent' } }); //bottom blue, overlay transparent



d3.selectAll('svg g.all g circle:nth-of-type(2)').on('mouseover', function(_, i) {
        d3.select(
                d3.select(this).node().parentElement.firstChild
            ).style('animation', 'move 1000ms infinite ease-in-out alternate')
            
    })
    .on('mouseout', function(_, i) {
        d3.select(
            d3.select(this).node().parentElement.firstChild
        ).style('animation', 'none')
    })
```

```css
#container>svg>g>g>circle:nth-child(1) {
    pointer-events: none;
}

@keyframes move {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(500px);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container" class="svg-container">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 600 100">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="530" height="200" fill="#EFEFEF"></rect>
      </svg>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="prod.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The animation actually works but it constantly resets itself.

The problem: your attaching the event listener to the animated circle.
As this circle will start to move on mouseover it will **almost immediately trigger the mouseout event.**

You should probably start and stop the animation when hovering the svg or rect instead.

```js
const svg = document.querySelector('svg');
const element = document.querySelector('.circ');
svg.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    element.style.animation = "move 1000ms infinite ease-in-out alternate";
});
svg.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
//mouseout triggers automatically following mouseover without provocation
    element.style.animation = "none";
});
```

```css
.circ {
     pointer-events: all;
}
 .rect {
     pointer-events: none;
}
 @keyframes move {
     0% {
         transform: translateX(0);
    }
     100% {
         transform: translateX(500px);
    }
}
```

```html
  <div id="container" class="svg-container">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 600 100">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="530" height="200" fill="#EFEFEF"></rect>
      <g class="crcl">  
        <circle class="circ" cx="10" cy="50" r="10" fill="blue"></circle>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
```

### Example2: start animation on hover; stop on click

```js
const svg = document.querySelector("svg");
const circles = document.querySelectorAll(".circ");

circles.forEach((circ) => {
  circ.addEventListener("mouseover", (e) => {
    let current = e.currentTarget;
    current.classList.add("running");
    //current.style.animation = "move 1000ms infinite ease-in-out alternate";
  });
});


svg.addEventListener("click", function() {
  togglePlayState(circles);
});

function togglePlayState(els) {
  els.forEach((el) => {
    let style = window.getComputedStyle(el);
    if (style.animationPlayState === "running") {
      //el.style.animationPlayState = "paused";
      el.classList.add("paused");
      el.classList.remove("running");

    } else if (el.classList.contains('paused')) {
      //el.style.animationPlayState = "running";
      el.classList.remove("paused");
      el.classList.add("running");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.circ {
  pointer-events: all;
}

.rect {}

.ani {
  animation: move 1000ms infinite ease-in-out alternate;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

.running {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

.paused {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(500px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="svg-container">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 600 100">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="530" height="200" fill="#EFEFEF"></rect>
      <g class="crcl">  
        <circle class="circ ani" cx="10" cy="50" r="10" fill="blue"></circle>
        <circle class="circ ani" cx="10" cy="75" r="10" fill="green"></circle>
      </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: This will work if I have only one circle. If I have multiple circles and I want each event to fire upon each circle mouseover, then it will not work as desired. Cause with the above, it will trigger all the circles to move at once and stop at once.

Comment: Please clarify, how the user interaction should work. However, stopping the animation on mouseout won't work (unless the user follows the circles while moving). I've added a 2nd example that will pause all animations on click. Besides, keep in mind mouseovers don't work well on mobile/touch devices – you might consider click events.